A man is framed as a killer because he was mistakenly thought he had a weapon
I watched this movie back in the late 80s / early 90s. (Color / English / Hollywood).
The only scene I remember is this man in his home/hotel room, wearing a bathrobe. He is thought to be holding a gun, and is shot by police (injured but not killed).
Later the police found out that he was holding a hair drier, not a gun. And they realize that they will be in trouble. So they made it look like he had a gun and that he tried to shoot first.
This guy ends up going to jail because of their tampering with evidence. 
He then plans escape/revenge.
Can't remember if he does, though.

Sounds like the film An Innocent Man featuring Tom Selleck.
This 1989 film features a key scene in which a drug bust goes wrong when an officer enters the wrong address and sees a man with a gun. The gun however is a hair dyer so they decide to plant evidence to protect themselves.
Here is a Wiki source:

After taking a large hit of cocaine Parnell becomes unable to
  concentrate properly about which address is next for a drug bust. But instead they break into the wrong house
  as Jimmie walks out of the bathroom with a handheld hair dryer, Parnell shoots thinking it's a weapon. Rainwood is shot in the
  shoulder and knocked unconscious. Realising that they could both be
  tested for taking drugs and charged they decide to cover up their
  mistake.

